# Removing duplicates from column A by the criteria in column D

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm currently working on a small report and can't get my head around a formula to remove duplicates.I have 4 main columns and I need to remove duplicates from column A basing on a data from column D.

Like in the example below - I need to remove **only** 3rd row, because it is ID duplicate and it was already marked as OLD in the column D in 1st row. Would be great to remove 1st row as it is older, but not significant at the moment.

I've tried to work with functions IF, IFS, Condition Formatting.
I can't do "Remove duplicates" as I need that there would be visible (if is) same ID for OLD and NEW.

E.g. `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>1,"dublicate","unique")`

I found duplicate, but not based on column D
In general I was not very successful.

```
A      B         C        D
ID_1   1 May     Acc_1    OLD
ID_2   1 May     Acc_1    OLD
ID_1   2 May     Acc_1    OLD
ID_1   5 May     Acc_2    NEW
```

I do not know how to make Excel look for duplicates in column A by the criteria "OLD" in column D.

Thank you in advance!
Philip

Comment: Formula can NOT remove rows/columns/cells. It can only calculate new value for its own cell when source cells values alters.

Comment: Select both column A and D and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using 'Remove Duplicates' found on the data tab.

Select Columns A:D,

Hit remove duplicates.

Then in the pop up box only have column A & D selected. see image below.

This will give you what you need.

[image]

Comment: I feel dumb... thank you, that worked perfectly.
But let say I have data for 1 year, but I need to prepare a report for each month. Should I just add a column JAN, FEB, etc. and include it in "Remove Duplicate" tool?

Comment: Yeah say the month is in column E, just make sure it is selected in pop up, have a play round with it, it will make more sense then. Click the little tick next to this answer to mark it as correct.

Comment: and don't feel dumb for asking a question, even the most super of users start off as novices :)